# Using two entities to create a single form

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I asked a similar question to this but I think it caused confusion so I decided to ask in this post with brushed up version.

What I want is to print all fields from two different entities in a single web form, **BOTH TYPE**. That's it.

Note: I tried using `entity` and `collection` keywords in the form type (*BOTH TYPE*) but twig doesn't echo anything. Keep getting; `Method "brand" OR "car" for object does not exist  in twig line whatever....`

Relationship: 1 `Brand` has N `Cars`. one-to-many

[image]

I read the 'How to Embed a Collection of Forms', 'entity Field Type' and 'collection Field Type' but whatever I did, didn't work.

**BRAND ENTITY**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class BrandEntity
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $origin;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "CarEntity", mappedBy = "brand")
     * @var object $car
     */
    protected $car;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->car = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**CAR ENTITY**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class CarEntity
{
    protected $id;
    protected $model;
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BrandEntity", inversedBy="car")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var object $brand
     */
    protected $brand;
}
```

**BRAND TYPE**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BrandType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
            ->add('origin', 'text', array('label' => 'Origin'))
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Car\BrandBundle\Entity\BrandEntity')
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'brand';
    }
}
```

**CAR TYPE**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('model', 'text', array('label' => 'Model'))
            ->add('price', 'text', array('label' => 'Price'))
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Car\BrandBundle\Entity\CarEntity')
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'car';
    }
}
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------**

**--------  This section is the one I'm trying to get it working ------**

**---------------------------------------------------------------------**

**BOTH TYPE**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BothType extends AbstractType
{
    public function builder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('brand', 'collection', array('type' => new BrandType()))
            ->add('car', 'collection', array('type' => new CarType()))
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Car\BrandBundle\Entity\BrandEntity',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'both';
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Controller;

use Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type\BothType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BothController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new BothType(), null,
            array('action' => $this->generateUrl('bothCreate')));;

        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Default:both.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Both', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

**TWIG**

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_label(form.brand.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.brand.name) }}
    {{ form_label(form.brand.origin) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.brand.origin) }}

    {{ form_label(form.car.model) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.car.model) }}
    {{ form_label(form.car.price) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.car.price) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: that's more code that i write in an average couple of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to composite the two objects in your controller.

```
$formData = array(
    'brand' = new Brand(),
    'car' => new Car(),
);
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($formData);
$builder->add('brand',new BrandFormType());
$builder->add('car', new CarFormType());

$form = $builder->getForm();

==============================================================
If you really want to make a BothType then just get rid of that collection type.

class BothType extends AbstractType
{
    public function builder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->setAction($options['action'])
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('brand', new BrandType())
        ->add('car', new CarType())
        ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
    ;
    }

    // Controller
    $form = $this->createForm(new BothType(), $formData
```

collection is used when you have multiple instances of the same entity type.

By the way, creating classes for each composite form can quickly cause an explosion of form types.  So unless you plan on reusing your BothFormType among multiple controllers then I'd suggest just building it right inside of the controller.

Comment: Yes it works but I don't use form builder in my controllers so how do I implement it into my code above?

Comment: For this create your form as services with the alias the same as the `getName()` and then you can use them like `->add('brand', 'the.alias.for.brand')`.

Comment: @Cerad - In your code, `$formData` has 'brand' and 'car' as array keys. What difference do they make? It seems to be working without them as well.

Comment: Hmmm.  That seems unlikely but I could be wrong.  The array keys are used to bind your form data to the objects.  Might be something else going on.

Comment: OK, I discovered. When I pass the array with or without keys, I get duplicated form submission. You can see output [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395912/assigning-value-to-data-class-in-form-type).